# Obtener dato de <select> y utilizarlo en <button>

Tags: javascript, html, html5, html-select

tengo un botón en HTML que añade un artículo al carrito tomando datos de los posts del CMS Ghost (son los que están entre dos llaves {{dato}}). Lo que quiero hacer es agregarle un dato más al botón tomando el dato de un "< select >". El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```html
<button id="addbuy"
    type='button'
    class='cart-button cart-add'
    data-id='{{id}}'
    data-label='{{title}}'
    data-price='{{custom_excerpt}}'
    data-image='{{img_url feature_image size="xs"}}'
    >
    Agregar al carrito
</button>
```

Y a dicho botón le quiero agregar el dato obtenido de:

```html
<select id="talle" name="talle">
    <option value="s">S</option> 
    <option value="m" selected>M</option>
    <option value="l">L</option>
    <option value="xl">XL</option>
</select>
```

Este es el javascript que tengo, lo que intenta hacer es:

1. Obtener el dato de "< select >"
2. Obtener el dato de "data-label" del botón.
3. Modificar el valor de "data-label" del botón, sumándole a este, el valor de "< select >"

```js
//Defino una variable local del Boton
let boton = document.getElementById('addbuy');
//Obtengo el valor del data-label del Boton (titulo del producto).
let dataLabel = boton.getAttribute("data-label");
//Defino una variable local del Select
let selectInput = document.getElementById('talle');
//Obtengo el valor de la opción seleccionada en el selectInput
let opcionSeleccionada = selectInput.options[selectInput.selectedIndex].value;
//Defino una variable que sume el título del producto + la opción seleccionada en el selectImput.
let titleProduct = dataLabel + opcionSeleccionada;
//Cambio el valor de "data-label" del Botón por el de la variable que tiene almacenado el nuevo título.
boton.setAttribute("data-label", titleProduct);
```

Este es el contexto del botón como para que se entienda lo que quiero hacer, como se puede observar, el título (nombre del producto) no se modifica ni en el botón ni en el carrito, debería aparecer algo como: "Campera Sky Azul M"
[image: contexto del boton]

Answer (score 0):

espero que esto te sirva:

Primero, agregué el atributo 'id' para el botón. Esto nos servirá, por un lado, para identificar el botón, y por otro, manipular el evento:

```
<button id="btn1"
type='button'
class='cart-button cart-add'
data-id='{{id}}'
data-label='{{title}}'
data-price='{{custom_excerpt}}'
data-image='{{img_url feature_image size="xs"}}'>
Agregar al carrito
</button>
```

Luego agregué el atributo 'id' al select input. En tu caso puse de 'id' el valor que tenía en 'name':

```
<select id="talle" name="talle">
    <option value="s">S</option> 
    <option value="m" selected>M</option>
    <option value="l">L</option>
    <option value="xl">XL</option>
</select>
```

Finalmente, Javascript:

```
//Referencia al botón mediante su id
let boton = document.getElementById('btn1');
//Referencia al select input mediante su id
let selectInput = document.getElementById('talle'); 
//Evento on click en nuestro botón
boton.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
//Obtengo el 'value' de la opción seleccionada en el input
let opcionSeleccionada = selectInput.options[selectInput.selectedIndex].value; 
//Le agrego el nuevo atributo, que lo llamé 'talle', y le doy de value la opción seleccionada.
boton.setAttribute("talle", opcionSeleccionada); 
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, cómo puedo hacer que dicho dato también se muestre en el "data-label", es decir, {{title}} + "talle" en el boton. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: De nada. Para hacer esto obtendríamos primero el value de 'data-label', luego lo concatenamos con el 'talle', y luego enviamos ese nuevo valor de nuevo a 'data-label': 

`let dataLabel = boton.getAttribute("data-label");
let nuevoValor = dataLabel + opcionSeleccionada;
boton.setAttribute("data-label", nuevoValor); `

Comment: Gracias nuevamente; por algún motivo no me funciona (no hay ningún error en la consola de chrome), el script no modifica el "data-label", voy a modificar el post para mostrarte como tengo el código.

Comment: Hola. El botón no tiene el id.

Comment: Hola, si tiene solo que en el post solo modifique agregando la parte de javascript, ahí modifico lo otro también así no confunde.